# Configuration binding extension could not be found

Tags: wcf, distributed-transactions

I am trying to get a WCF webservice running which will participate in distributed transactions.  I keep getting the following error message...

> Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/myBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly

Here is the web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name = "DistServiceX">
    <endpoint
       address=""
       binding="myBinding"
       contract="IDistService"
     />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding
      name="myBinding" 
      transactionFlow="true"
      />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?  It's driving me crazy!

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are referring to a custom binding here:

```
<service name = "DistServiceX">
   <endpoint
       address=""
       binding="myBinding"
      contract="IDistService" />
```

However, there is no custom binding called `myBinding` anywhere in your config.

I assume you really want to refer to a `wsHttpBinding` and the `myBinding` binding **configuration** that you specified in your config file. Furthermore: the name of the service must match the fully qualified name of the class that implements the service - including namespace (and also: the name of the contract being implemented by that service and exposed on a given endpoint must include any namespaces):

```
<service name="YourNamespace.DistServiceX">
   <endpoint
       address=""
       binding="wsHttpBinding" 
       bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
       contract="YourNamespace.IDistService" />
```

Comment: You are correct. In addition though I also had to fully quality the IDistService interface with a namespace and also specify the namespace.class of the implementing class instead of "DistServiceX"

Comment: Hi Marc.  Can you include that in your response? Once the response is complete I can accept it as an answer.  It'll just be more helpful for others in future if all of the problems with the config are mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: THANKYOU! As a front-end developer I was struggling with googling this issue, but you explained it VERY WELL.